# How do I read and write to user accessible directory in android code?

Tags: java, android, file, io, filesystems

I am new to app development and want to read and write files from a user accessible directory such as documents on Android. Everything I've found online doesn't work or writes to hidden files.

I want to be able to read basic text files and pictures from a directory and sub-directories for processing. I need to read from the internal storage in the same directories as DCIM, Download, Music, etc.

I need a full breakdown of how to do it. I'm coding for Android 6 and up on Android Studio. I only have access to internal storage on my dev phone.

Thanks in advance. Sorry for being a noob.

I don't really know what is applicable for background. I don't fully understand how the Android file system and permissions work.

My dev phone is a Google Pixel 3a with android 10.

Here is my project code:
Manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nbradham.rwtest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main Activity:

```java
package nbradham.rwtest;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("############");
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[]
            permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        System.out.println("Perm...");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        System.out.println("Reading...");
                        try {
                            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download/loadme.txt");
                            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
10/02 18:34:50: Launching 'app' on Google Pixel 3a.
$ adb shell am start -n "nbradham.rwtest/nbradham.rwtest.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for process to come online...
Connected to process 5611 on device 'google-pixel_3a-93KAY0C208'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/nbradham.rwtes: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
E/nbradham.rwtes: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
I/System.out: ############
I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 4a00b69, I4e7e888065
    Build Date                       : 04/09/19
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.26.06.00
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
    Build Config                     : S P 8.0.6 AArch64
I/Adreno: PFP: 0x016ee183, ME: 0x00000000
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
I/System.out: Perm...
    Reading...
I/System.out: /storage/emulated/0/Download/loadme.txt
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/loadme.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
        at nbradham.rwtest.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:39)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:8264)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8114)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4838)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7255)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
        ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to Put Permission First in Manifiest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

then you have to ask permission in runtime on above marshmellow device:

```
private void requestPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[] {
                    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
           // do your code if permission granteed
        }
    }
```

and then you have to catch the permission on onActvitiyResult overriden method

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[]
            permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) && grantResults.length > 0 && permissions[1].equals(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    // check whether storage permission granted or not.
                    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                       // do you stuff if your permission is granted
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I successfully acquire permissions for writing to the external directory (like a SD card), I think, but my device does not have external storage. I need to be able to read from a directory next to the internal user data (DCIM, Download, Pictures, etc.)

Comment: so you cant get internal storage dir using getexternalStorage()"?

Comment: That does return the correct path, but I'm still unable to write and read from it. It appears that in Android 10, they massively changed how storage permissions work. The old method of just simply asking for permission only works for the directory specific to the app. It won't let you write to the main public storage.